# What is a keyExtractor parameter

Tags: java, comparator

I'm learning the `Comparator` interface and I'm confused with it's static `Comparator.comparing()` method. About `Comparator.comparing()` method's parameters and how it can use method references. When I looked at the documentations it says that that it has a "keyExtractor parameter". Can you explain what is confusing me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Comparator#comparing(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)):

> Accepts a function that extracts a `Comparable` sort key from a type `T`, and returns a `Comparator<T>` that compares by that sort key.

It's so you can compare objects based on a property of those objects. The same documentation gives an example:

> **API Note:**
>
> For example, to obtain a `Comparator` that compares `Person` objects by their last name,
>
> ```java
> Comparator<Person> byLastName = Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName);
> ```

When you do:

```java
Person p1 = ...;
Person p2 = ...;
int result = byLastName.compare(p1, p2);
```

The given key extractor will extract the last name values from each `Person` in order to compare those values rather than the `Person` objects "directly". If the key is not `Comparable` then you can use [the overload](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)) which lets you specify a `Comparator` for comparing the extracted key values.

---

The above `byLastName` comparator would be the same as:

```java
public class ByLastNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    return p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName());
  }
}
```

Where the calls to `p1.getLastName()` and `p2.getLastName()` would be the key extractor `Function` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

> From [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) : `keyExtractor` - the function used to extract the Comparable sort key

This means, it is a function to find out which parameters of the given elements, should be taken to evaluate the position between each elements

Imagine a class like

```
class Elt {
    int a, b;
    float c;
    public int getA() { return a; }
    public int getB() { return b; }
    public float getC() { return c; }
}
```

You can use several keys to compare them, `a`, `b` or `c`

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    List<Elt> res = Arrays.asList(new Elt(), new Elt());
    res.sort(Comparator.comparing(Elt::getA)); // elt -> elt.getA()
    res.sort(Comparator.comparing(Elt::getB)); // elt -> elt.getB()
    res.sort(Comparator.comparing(Elt::getC)); // elt -> elt.getC()
}
```

`Comparator` also allows to chain `keyExtractor` using `thenComparing`

```
// differentiate element with same 'c' for ex
res.sort(Comparator.comparing(Elt::getC).thenComparing(Elt::getA));
```