# explain on keyExtractor more further

Tags: java

I am learning on how the `Comparator<T>` works. I have taken a look on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60694693/7738154). But I still have some confused...

Here is the interface of Comparator.comparing

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

The following statement gives me a `Comparator<Person>`

```
Comparator<Person> byLastName = Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName);
```

Assume the person.getLastName takes on arg and return String. Person::getLastName doesn't add up with the interface `Function<T, U>` which should take T as input class and U as return class. My best guess is that U is the String class. But how about T? (I know it should be Person, but it doesn't make sense to me)

And the following implementation doesn't make any sense to me as well.

```
(c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
```

I guess c1 and c2 are person instances. But why we need to call apply method with c1 class?

This whole think doesn't make sense to me. Would you please explain further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill try to make it a little simpler.

```
class A{
    int value;
    public A(int v){
        value = v;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

So we have a class we want to compare based on it's value. So to use `comparing` we need a method that returns the value. So in this case, T would be class A, and U would be an Integer. (There is an override for `int`).

So our `Function` needs to take an A as an argument (or a super to A) and return a comparable object.

```
Function<A, Integer> keyExtractor = a -> a.getValue();
```

The implementation you've provided.

```
A c1 = new A(5);
A c2 = new A(10);
```

If we want to compare these values.

```
Integer i1 = keyExtractor.apply(c1);
Integer i2 = keyExtractor.apply(c2);
```

Then compare them.

```
i1.compareTo(i2);
```

So in your example it is using a lambda, so you wouldn't know what c1 and c2 are.

```
(c1, c2)->keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
```

or it is like writing a method.

```
public int compare(A c1, A c2){
     
    Integer i1 = keyExtractor.apply(c1);
    Integer i2 = keyExtractor.apply(c2);

    return i1.compareTo(i2);    
}
```

I hope this helps, because sometimes generics seem especially complicated because of the `? super T`. In my "simple" example there isn't a class that is super of A but still has a 'getValue'.

Comment: it turns out that this is caused by my misunderstanding of Function interface and lambda expression. Thanks buddy for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since `getLastName()` is an instance method (=not declared static), we must specify which instance the method should be invoked on.

For a method reference, this can be done in two different ways:

- we can provide the object when constructing the method reference, by writing `person::getLastName`, which is shorthand for `() -> person.getLastName()`.
- or we can defer this to the caller of the method reference, by writing `Person::getLastName`, which is shorthand for `(person) -> person.getLastName()`. Since this lambda takes a `Person` and returns a `String`, it is compatible with `Function<Person, String>`.

> And the following implementation doesn't make any sense to me as well
>
> (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));

If keyExtractor is `Person::getLastName()`, `keyExtractor.apply(c1)` means `c1.getLastName()`, and `keyExtractor.apply(c2)` means `c2.getLastName()`. That is, the above code means

```
(c1, c2) -> c1.getLastName().compareTo(c2.getLastName())
```

And that's why we need the `keyExtractor` for `c1` as well as `c2`: We want to compare the last name of `c1` with the last name of `c2`.